# How to filter data from tables and display it in DataGridView?

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and SQL.

[image: screenshot]

As show in screenshot, I am trying to filter data from multiple tables and insert it into the DataDridView. 
I have 3 tables:

- Orders.
- Order_Details
- Products.

I want to filter order_Id 2 (Sam), I want to display what did he order into DataGridView based on his order_ID. I want to display his data as follow:

- customer name
- product name
- Qty
- price

According to my code, I know how to display the "Order_details" table but I do not know how to display Sam' order details into DataGridView. I maean I want to extract data of Sam from the 3 tables and show it in the DataGridView.
please help me how to achieve this. Thank you

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {   // display Order_details table into DataGridView

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=PCN11-TOSH;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT *FROM Order_details");
        cm.Connection = con;

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cm);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        con.Close();

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

}

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any idea what you are expected to do? Sorry to be blunt be this smells like homework... and I don't want to do your homework for you.

Comment: @TimBourguignon homeworks are on-topic on SO as long as `Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.` ..

Comment: @otopolsky: which is exactly the point I am missing. I assume that someone who found out how to create an SQL connection and display the resulting information in a datagrid on his own would also come out with the idea that a filtering (WHERE clause) and some kind of combining (JOIN) would be required for the rest and ask for specific help. With my nasty-hat-on, I could even interpret it as "the SQL connection was part of the homework and naouf didn't do anything else than the SELECT *"... see what I mean?

Comment: @ Tim Bourguignon. probably you did not read my question, can't you see the code? . May be it is you who posts homework here not me. anyway if you can't help don't comment in silly way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh I'm not as shy about giving out homework answers. This is more a SQL question than a C# question. If you wanted to solve this with code, I'd implement a ORM and shape your data into the Grid using LINQ. Since your original question involves only a SqlAdapter, the answer lies in the query.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {   // display Order_details table into DataGridView

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=PCN11-TOSH;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT o.customer_name, p.product_name, d.Qty, p.price FROM Orders
                                         JOIN order_details d ON d.order_ID = o.order_ID
                                         JOIN products p ON p.product_ID = d.product_ID");
        cm.Connection = con;

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cm);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        con.Close();

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: @ S. Brentson . it worked well. thank you. but i have very important question: your code worked with and without using primary and foreign keys. I removed primary and foreign keys and your code still working, so why can't we use them in this situation? i mean how can we get advantage of them? thank you.

Comment: Foreign keys are among other things constraints. Without them, it's up to whomever is interacting with the database to ensure referential integrity. The database works without them. In many cases, these keys are also used as cues to define relationships between tables. Again, without them, it's up to whomever is interacting with the database to respect the relationships. The DataAdapter has the ability to formulate relationships based on these keys. In our case, we defined our own view (SqlCommand) that respected the relationships, but otherwise did not use them.

Comment: If you want to take advantage of these relationships and keys, you can look into DataSets. Here's a document on how to fill a DataSet [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233773.aspx). I did not offer this as a solution because it's more involved and will require that you study this paradigm before asking any questions on here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `join` and then `select data` from `database` and `bind` it to gridview.

```
select Distinct o.customer_name,od.qty,p.product_name,p.price from orders o
inner join order_details od on o.orderid=od.orderid
inner join products p on p.productid=od.product_id
where o.order_id=1
```